# powerpoint flowchart to html

Tags: html, powerpoint, flowchart

I have the following
[image](http://www.imagebam.com/image/3b5bf6192161966) as a powerpoint flow chart (text with hyperlinks not shown).

I want to turn this chart into an html-website. 
Any ideas how to get a good result for this task?

I think recreating this with coding in html is troublesome.

Thank you.

Comment: Aside from using the image with some invisible link overlays or an imagemap on top, this is a pretty tall order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text on gray backgrounds (5 on right, 2 on left) are probably headings of the same level so they would be hN floating on the right and coming before each set of arrows.

Each individual set of arrows can be fairly easily coded as lists and styled as these breadcrumbs:

- [Simple scalable CSS based breadcrumbs](http://veerle-v2.duoh.com/blog/comments/simple_scalable_css_based_breadcrumbs/) (by Veerle Pieters)
- [Breadcrumb Navigation with CSS Triangles](http://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/) (by Chris Coyer)

They can expand with content if it seldomly occupies 2 lines (Firefox/Ubuntu and Safari/Mac have laaarge fonts, don't assume that your text will always stay on 1 line. Not speaking of zoom text that should be [taken into account](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-scale.html))

As for orange arrows between individual series ... that's complicated enough without HTML so it depends of context I believe. Is this an industrial process, webmarketing or else? To make it accessible, I'd use HTML images with alternative text trying to describe relationship.

Red arrows could be anchor links, probably.

Comment: thanks for the links. Been playing with the 2nd link for a while now. The only issue I have is that I want the first arrow of each row to also have this "arrow indent" on its left side -> in my image the left most arrows. Any ideas how to set this up?

Comment: No `:before` or `:after` are defined for the parent `ul.breadcrumb` so I'd use it with the same technique used for inner arrows. It gives sth like `.breadcrumb:after {
    border-bottom: 25px solid red;
    border-left: 15px solid green;
    border-top: 25px solid blue;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
}`. Then some margin (padding?) on the first link to compensate for the new arrow: `.breadcrumb li:first-child a { margin-left: 10px; /* or 15? To be determined */ }`

Answer (score 0):

I Think this image can be optimized pretty good, as it doesn't have a very complicated graphic. Therefore an easy solution can be just including it as an background image and then you can set the text and links into place using css.

A better solution is to break the picture into smaller components, then this way you can define "div" s with the background-color, border, and border-radios as the gray parts, and set the white elements as the background-image of "a" tag... However for the arrows I think you should include them as background-image...

Hope this helped...